# In article documentclass how to denote different "parts" of an article?

Tags: chapters, document-classes

Well I'm building a technical documentation. As it's not meant to be a full report with table of contents etc, I opted going for the article documentclass (Or more specifically the Hitec class, but that's based on article right?).

The documentent will exist of three "parts" though, which are only loosely bound together. - Two parts have been separate articles of their own, with a third part added as a review of the combination of the two parts.

The parts would be "labeled" `A`, `B` and `C`, with section numbering starting over each part. (This would be especially nice since `A` and `B` follow the same logical structure, so `A.1` and `B.1` would be about the same topics).

What style is often used for such "bundles" or part-based articles? Is using the actual report class and just using chapters the better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`article`, and apparently also `hitec`, has a `\part` sectioning command, so something like this could be an option, perhaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{hitec}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{section}{part}
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}

\title{Stuff}
\author{Some Dude}

\begin{document}
\part{Foo}
\section{bar}
\part{Baz}
\section{Etc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want page breaks before each `\part`? If so, add `\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand\part{\clearpage\oldpart}`